# How to return a single result object from hibernate query?

Tags: hibernate

Does a query execution always have to return a list ? How do I replace the code below if I am sure it will only return a single object ?

```
@Override
    public List<DocInfo> findAllByDocId(String docId)
    {
        Query q = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from DocInfo item where item.id = :docId");
        q.setString("docId", docId);
        List<DocInfo> docInfoList = q.list();
        return docInfoList;
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use [Query#uniqueResult()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29) with Hibernate if I am not wrong. I think that is what you are looking for. In this case, you have to handle the `NonUniqueResultException` in your code if there is more than one row returned from your query.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
query.getSingleResult();
```

when you are absolutely sure that query would return only one row and I am talking about

```
import javax.persistence.Query;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading by id (pk), as it appears you are here, you really should use Session.load/Session.get instead.