# Can we get single object from hql query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am writing a select query in hql , my task is to activate the bus. First I will get a messege from client as `busId#busStatus`, so first I look for this perticular busId is active or inactive So I have to write select query but in hibernate `query.list()` returns `list`. Here I think list is unnecessary , a single object is enough .

Here is my code ,

```
    String hql="from BusDetailBean where Busid= :busId and bus_status=:busStatus";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("busId", busId);
        query.setParameter("busStatus", busStatus);

        List<BusDetailBean> busDetails=(List<BusDetailBean>)query.list(); 
       if(busDetails.isEmpty())
        {
             //my other stuff
        }
         else
         {

            //bus ativation stuff
         }
```

My question is the select query returns only one object if list is not empty I have to use for loop in else part. So how can I optimise this code. can anyone help me in this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427725/does-hibernate-query-result-always-return-a-list

Comment: What about `busDetails.iterator().next();` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `query.getSingleResult()`

Comment: Which throws RuntimeException in case there is no result. I don't know if it is desirable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I used `query.uniqueResult();`

Comment: what's happening if there is no result?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `query.setMaxResults(1);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I used `query.uniqueResult();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the object at index 0 in the list:

```
List l = query.list() 
if (l.size()>0) {
  return l.get(0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I used `query.uniqueResult();`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think persitence should be mixed with business logic.

What about returning Optional from the persitence layer and whether result is present/absent do something in higher level?

In persistance layer something like:

`return query.list()
    .stream()
    .findFirst()`

This, according to docs, will return first result or empty optional if the collection was empty.

And then:

```
Optional<Bus> optionalBus = repository.find(busId, busStatus);
if (optionalBus.isPresent()) {
    something here
} else {
    something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,but  I used query.uniqueResult();

Comment: Keep in mind it could return null when there is no match or even throw runtime exception given more than one result.

Answer (score 0):

by using query.uniqueResult() you don't ensure that if you have many results , then you will get only one of them.

With uniqueResult() you place a guard/contraint at your result set to be aware that this query should always return a unique result.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem, the out of the box solution in `Hibernate` is to use the `uniqueResult()` method in the `Query` class:

```
public Object uniqueResult()
```

From the `Hibernate` JavaDocs:

> Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query,
>   or `null` if the query returns no results.
>
> Returns: the single result or `null`
>
> Throws:
>
> - `NonUniqueResultException` - if there is more than one matching result
> - `HibernateException`